# Submit form with ajax and post to to pages

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

A bit of a tricky one here
Is there a way i can join the two scripts below into one so when the form is posted it actually loads both the different named url's into the 2 different named divs

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#profile").validate({
     debug: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {$.post('brides_Includes/edit-profile-top.php', $("#profile").serialize(), function(data) {
       $('#results').html(data);
        //This executes the JavaScript passed back by the ajax.
        $("#results").find("script").each(function(i) {
          eval($(this).text());
        });

        $("form#profile")[0].reset();
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#profile").validate({
     debug: false,
    submitHandler: function(form) {$.post('brides_Includes/welcome-menu.php', $("#profile").serialize(), function(data) {
       $('#mymenu').html(data);
        //This executes the JavaScript passed back by the ajax.
        $("#mymenu").find("script").each(function(i) {
          eval($(this).text());
        });

        $("form#profile")[0].reset();
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

I am not sure if this is even possible but would be great if it was :)
Many thanks

Comment: Hi The divs are named as results and mymenu

Comment: What do you mean by combine the scripts?  They are mutually exclusive

Comment: single form posting called profile and loading results data into results and mymenu

Comment: when the form is posted it runs the first one but not the second one into mymenu

Comment: Proper indenting and spacing goes a long way towards more successful troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the contents of the second `submitHandler` into the first one:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
   var jqxhr1 = $.post('brides_Includes/edit-profile-top.php', $("#prof...
   function(data) {
       $('#results').html(data);
        //This executes the JavaScript passed back by the ajax.
        $("#results").find("script").each(function(i) {
          eval($(this).text());
        });
      });
    }
  var jqxhr2 = $.post('brides_Includes/welcome-menu.php', $("#pro...
  function(data) {
   $('#mymenu').html(data);
    //This executes the JavaScript passed back by the ajax.
    $("#mymenu").find("script").each(function(i) {
      eval($(this).text());
    });

  $.when(jqxhr1, jqhxr2).done(function() { $("#profile")[0].reset(); });
}
```

Comment: Tried both of those ways and each time it loads the first one ok but does not load the second one

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function ajax_loadpage(loadUrl,output_container)
    {
        $.post
        (
            loadUrl,
            {language: "php", version: 5},function(responseText){$(output_container).html(responseText);},"html"
        );
    }

ajax_loadpage("url1.php","#div1");
ajax_loadpage("url2.php","#div2");

</script>
```

the first parameter should be supplied with the URL you want to load, the second will be the name of the id of the element you want to load it into.

Comment: just call the function within your element event, or like here, the function will be executed once the page is load

Comment: I also got around this by wrapping everything into the same div